# GUnicorn and Django for 500 concurrent requests with limited resources

Tags: django, nginx, concurrency, gunicorn

I was tasked with creating a Django-Gunicorn demo app. In this task, I need to be able to handle 500 concurrent login requests in 1 second.

I have to deploy the app in a VM with 2GB RAM and 2 core CPUs (using Vagrant and VirtualBox, Ubuntu 16.04). I already tried the following for deployment.

`gunicorn --workers 5 --bind "0.0.0.0:8000" --worker-class "gevent" --keep-alive 5 project.wsgi`

Using JMeter test from the host machine, the test always takes around 7-10 seconds. Even if the login endpoint only returns empty response without any database access, the amount of the time is almost the same. Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

I use the default settings at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And here is my reverse proxy settings I put in sites-available folder.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /vagrant/static/;
    }

    location /media {
    autoindex on;
    alias /vagrant/uploads/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably won't get any solid answer or help as we don't know what is your nginx settings and how the nginx pass the request to the WSGI server (i.e. gunicorn). e.g. what is your setting for ` multi_accept` within your `http` directive? Furthermore, when you running under a development/local server, what is the response time (compare to 7-10s under gunicorn)?

Comment: @hcheung Hi! I've updated my question. Apparently, using `python manage.py runserver`, the speed is also the same :(.

Comment: If you have the same response time when running on Django build-in server, then the problem is your python script, as it neither using the nginx nor the gunicorn. As for your nginx configuration, try to lower the `keepalive_timeout` and increase the `worker_connections`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you miss [worker connections](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-connections) in gunicorn. So it cannot handle more concurrent requests.

For 500 concurrent login requests, the concurrent active connections handled by the database is also important. If the database cannot handle the loading, you are going to fail too. If you're using PSQL, you have to change max connections and use a connection pool